# How to filter rows in CTE by latest column value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I'm attempting to use a CTE to filter out some rows in snowflake based off the latest version.

| id | version |
| --- | --- |
| brand_a | 1 |
| brand_a | 2 |
| brand_b | 1 |
| brand_c | 1 |

```
with brands as (
    select
        id
        , version
        , row_number() over (
            partition by id
            order by version desc
        ) as row_number
    from brand_table
)
select id, version from brands where row_number = 1;
```

This seems to work for rows where we can filter on timestamps but in this case I need to filter by the latest version. Ideally, I'd like for the following to be returned:

| id | version |
| --- | --- |
| brand_a | 2 |
| brand_b | 1 |
| brand_c | 1 |

but doesn't work since it's returning rows where row_number = 1 and I can't seem to figure out how to query the rows with the latest version for each id. Is using `row_number()` even the appropriate path?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include `cash_card_parent_merchant_token` and `brand_id` in your simple data  ?

Comment: It appears to be working, what you get as a result ?

Answer (score 0):

Then thats simple, without CTE:

```
SELECT id, MAX(version)
FROM brand_table
GROUP BY id;
```